# resolving curl and utf-8 supporting

Tags: php, curl, utf-8, persian

i have one site with code:

```
<... html code here ...>
مثال
<... html code here ...>
```

i used curl lib to read this page.
but result return is:

```
<... html code here ...>
����ɂ���
<... html code here ...>
```

i used `utf8_encode` , `decode`... but it takes no effect.

so then, did CURL support UTF8 ?

html content are ok , but i want to show personal messeges that every time will be updated , everything are ok , but messege turns to question mark :|

this is my curl attribs :

```
  $login = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
    //  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        if ($proxystatus == 'on') {
            curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        }
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        ob_start();      // prevent any output
        return curl_exec ($login); // execute the curl command
        ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output
        curl_close ($login);
        unset($login);
```

what i must do?

Comment: you are like editors that want to edit

tell me a real answer for my question:|

Comment: Did you try `iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $myStr)` instead of `utf8_decode` & co? This did the trick for me… Though I still don't understand why I, also, receive ISO instead of UTF-8.